# Trouble with fiber modem

Tags: dhcp, ipv4, fiber

My neighborhood just activated fiber service to the home (http://fiber.usinternet.com/ in Minneapolis), but I'm having trouble connecting downstream devices to the modem.  It's a CTC Union GSW-1005MS device provided by US Internet.

- If I plug my laptop (**MacBook Pro running Sierra 10.12.5**) directly into the CTC device, it works fine - negotiates a DHCP connection and I can access the internet.  It gets an IP address in the 67.220.12.x range, and the gateway is 67.220.12.1.
- Initially I tried to connect my existing wireless router (a **UniFi AP AC LR** device) to it, but it didn't connect properly.  I suspect it couldn't negotiate an IP address through DHCP or something, but I couldn't tell.  It's also possible something didn't like the POE injector that the UniFi uses, but the combination had worked fine with my previous DSL setup.
- I went out and bought a **TP-Link Archer C2600** wireless router instead, that connected & started providing internet service with zero trouble.  All devices connected downstream of it work fine.
- I'm trying to connect my existing Vonage phone adapter (**Motorola VT2142-VD**) to the CTC via Ethernet.  It can't find its Vonage home base, displaying the "two blinks - pause - repeat" sequence that [its docs](https://support.vonage.com/articles/answer/Motorola-VT2142-Telephone-Adapter-864) say means it's trying to obtain an IP address.
- If I plug the Vonage device directly into the TP-Link router (see above), it works fine.

Is it possible that the CTC is using some flavor of DHCP that some of my devices don't like?  Is it strange that my private subnet is in the 67.220.12.x range?  I've never seen that before, and it's not within the normal set of [reserved IP ranges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses).

The fiber provider seems to have disabled the CTC's web interface (at least on the LAN side), so it's kind of hard to figure out what it's seeing.

Comment: "Private subnet"? You're assuming that the CTC is a router. It probably isn't, and you're talking directly to the ISP. There is no "private subnet" in there.

Answer (score 2):

Bit of guesswork here - the "CTC" device is an ONT - *some* places let you run more than one provider or connection on it, but by default it is configured for only one. If you had say, a 2gbps setup *or* something odd like two ISPs with the same fibre opco, you might be able to run different ISPs on it

Your "router" is a [pure access point](https://www.ubnt.com/unifi/unifi-ap-ac-lr/) and lacks a DHCP server of its own - its meant to be run with another system doing those things. Your old ADSL setup probably had a modem router.

That *might* not be a ip address range - its plausible your 
ONT has an IP address for management, and issues one ip address to whatever.

Answer (score 1):

I got some enlightenment from the excellent customer support at USInternet, after I asked them to look at this question on SU.

1. There are 5 ethernet ports on the CTC device, but only port 1 is enabled for internet access.  Port 2 is for their internet phone service (which we don't have), and ports 3-5 are reserved for future use.  That's why no other device worked in ports 2-5, despite connection lights turning on.
2. Only 1 MAC address is allowed to connect to port 1, so basically that has to be a router (not, e.g., a switch) if I want to have more than one connected device in my house.

Still not totally sure why the UniFi AP didn't connect - the support person said it might be because the UniFi is supposed to work as a network extender and be subservient to a router, but I thought it was supposed to work as a standalone access point if necessary.

Comment: These days, "Standalone access point" has two, nearly opposite meanings. You're expecting it to mean a router (like in DDWRT), but the original meaning of AP is actually a pure "network extender", as you would call it. That's what UniFi APs are: Wi-Fi radios (extenders) with no routing function.

Comment: Ah, yes, yet _another_ meaning of "standalone" is that they normally use a central UniFi controller, but can work without. The controller, however, has nothing to do with routing – it's merely used to distribute configuration across many APs. When you have only one or two, "standalone" would mean configuring it via the app instead.

Answer (score 0):

A UniFi AP is an AP, not a router. Despite legions of people who don't understand the difference, there is one.

If you connected a UniFi USG (which IS a router) it would work fine. Or you could use a pfSense or any other router you like.

You have a modem, and you need a router, and you need APs (if you want WiFi, anyway) but they don't need to be in the same box. One is not the other, no matter how many people don't grasp the distinction.